# Add Expire headers to ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, apache, http-headers

Programmatically how do i add expire header? I am not using IIS, i'd like to do this in ASP.NET itself or maybe how to do it with apache which is what i am using.

Answer (score 2):

See [How to: Set Expiration Values for ASP.NET Page Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y18he7cw(v=VS.85).aspx)

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

If you set expirations for a page programmatically, you must set the Cache-Control header for the cached page as well. To do so, call the SetCacheability method and pass it the HttpCacheability enumeration value Public